# pip install -r requirements.txt throws an error when using venv instead of anaconda python

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-venv, requirements.txt

when I use anaconda python I can install this requirements.txt with no problem using pip install -r requirements.txt however, when I use venv, I get this error. Do you know how I can fix it? https://pastebin.com/raw/9eUc7H9x

```
[101243:4668 0:2014] 06:30:09 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/13 +1] ~/research/code/DJ-RN
$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (516.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 516.3 MB 12 kB/s 
Collecting pillow==8.0.1
  Downloading Pillow-8.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.2 MB 5.4 MB/s 
Collecting six==1.15.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting sympy==1.6.2
  Downloading sympy-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.8 MB 9.2 MB/s 
Collecting opencv-python==4.4.0.46
  Using cached opencv_python-4.4.0.46-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (49.5 MB)
Collecting h5py==2.10.0
  Downloading h5py-2.10.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.9 MB 7.2 MB/s 
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.2
  Downloading matplotlib-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 11.6 MB 6.1 MB/s 
Collecting numpy==1.19.2
  Downloading numpy-1.19.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.5 MB 9.9 MB/s 
Collecting pyrr==0.10.3
  Using cached pyrr-0.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Collecting requests==2.24.0
  Downloading requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61 kB 1.5 MB/s 
Collecting trimesh==3.8.19
  Using cached trimesh-3.8.19-py3-none-any.whl (627 kB)
Collecting smplx
  Using cached smplx-0.1.26-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Processing /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/a0/16/9c/5473df82468f958445479c59e784896fa24f4a5fc024b0f501/termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/5f/fd/9e/b6cf5890494cb8ef0b5eaff72e5d55a70fb56316007d6dfe73/wrapt-1.12.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3"
  Downloading wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting gast==0.3.3
  Using cached gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0
  Downloading tensorboard-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.0 MB 6.4 MB/s 
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.8
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3"
  Downloading scipy-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.0 MB 12.7 MB/s 
Collecting protobuf>=3.8.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.14.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting absl-py>=0.7.0
  Using cached absl_py-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0
  Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (454 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 454 kB 9.0 MB/s 
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6
  Using cached grpcio-1.34.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.0 MB)
Collecting mpmath>=0.19
  Downloading mpmath-1.1.0.tar.gz (512 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 512 kB 8.7 MB/s 
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 67 kB 6.4 MB/s 
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 10.6 MB/s 
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 227 kB 8.4 MB/s 
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2020.06.20
  Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 147 kB 6.3 MB/s 
Collecting multipledispatch
  Downloading multipledispatch-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 127 kB 10.8 MB/s 
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 11.4 MB/s 
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 4.6 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/mona/venv/djrn/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from trimesh==3.8.19->-r requirements.txt (line 11)) (44.0.0)
Collecting torchgeometry>=0.1.2
  Using cached torchgeometry-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting torch>=1.0.1.post2
  Downloading torch-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (776.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 776.8 MB 12 kB/s 
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 298 kB 8.7 MB/s 
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (779 kB)
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Using cached google_auth-1.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached Markdown-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions
  Downloading typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.6"
  Using cached rsa-4.6-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mpmath
  Building wheel for mpmath (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/mona/venv/djrn/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mgornyum/mpmath/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mgornyum/mpmath/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-b7gvke1h
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mgornyum/mpmath/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpmath
  Running setup.py clean for mpmath
Failed to build mpmath
Installing collected packages: termcolor, numpy, six, h5py, wrapt, wheel, gast, opt-einsum, werkzeug, tensorboard-plugin-wit, grpcio, protobuf, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, cachetools, google-auth, absl-py, certifi, urllib3, chardet, idna, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, markdown, tensorboard, google-pasta, keras-preprocessing, scipy, tensorflow-estimator, astunparse, tensorflow-gpu, pillow, mpmath, sympy, opencv-python, pyparsing, kiwisolver, python-dateutil, cycler, matplotlib, multipledispatch, pyrr, trimesh, typing-extensions, torch, torchgeometry, smplx
    Running setup.py install for mpmath ... done
Successfully installed absl-py-0.11.0 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-4.2.0 certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-3.0.4 cycler-0.10.0 gast-0.3.3 google-auth-1.24.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.2 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.34.0 h5py-2.10.0 idna-2.10 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 kiwisolver-1.3.1 markdown-3.3.3 matplotlib-3.3.2 mpmath-1.1.0 multipledispatch-0.6.0 numpy-1.19.2 oauthlib-3.1.0 opencv-python-4.4.0.46 opt-einsum-3.3.0 pillow-8.0.1 protobuf-3.14.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pyparsing-2.4.7 pyrr-0.10.3 python-dateutil-2.8.1 requests-2.24.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.6 scipy-1.4.1 six-1.15.0 smplx-0.1.26 sympy-1.6.2 tensorboard-2.2.2 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.7.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.2.0 tensorflow-gpu-2.2.0 termcolor-1.1.0 torch-1.7.1 torchgeometry-0.1.2 trimesh-3.8.19 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 urllib3-1.25.11 werkzeug-1.0.1 wheel-0.36.2 wrapt-1.12.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ pip install pip --upgrade


$ pip install setuptools --upgrade
```